# Themeroller radius not working anymore?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with the themeroller.. the thing is that i want to have a radius on my buttons and when i use TR to so it shows up on their sample swatch but when i download the style and want to use it the buttons are not rounded at all

[Here you can see a sample of what i mean](http://yellowgreenmedia.nl/2/)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Change the **data-inset** from false to true in your  tag

Comment: Efthimis thank you very very much, you have no idea how much this simple tip has helped me out